# XHR.statusText error when aborting angular $http requests

Tags: angularjs

So I have recently implemented a means to cancel an $http request via the timeout property by passing in and resolving a promise.

When a request is aborted the $http promise goes to the error block. This is all fine, its after this all finishes processing I receive an error from angular.js (xdomain.js is in the call stack) stating that it "Cannot read property 'statusText' of null". Null being the xhr object.

I'm at a loss currently as the request is successfully being cancelled, but it seems as if the xhr object is being destroyed right after calling xhr.onload().

Here's an example of how I'm cancelling the request:

```
var request = {
    url: 'someurl',
    method: 'get',
    headers: headers
    timeout: canceller // this is a promise that I resolve in a controller in order to abort an $http request. This works fine.
}

$http(request).then(function () { 
//success block 
}, function () { 
// error block 
});
```

As I said, it enters the error block but it isn't inside of that block that the angular error is thrown, rather it seems to be with the request comes back and there is no longer an xhr object waiting for it that an error occurs.

Comment: Can you post the code, or enough of it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Edited to include code. Didn't include the code initially because it's a fairly generic implementation of aborting a $http request. It isn't this block of code that gives the error only after it finishes running.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Angular and Xdomain. A workaround I'm fond of is passing in a unique identifier or bool when submitting the request. If the value has changed when the request is completed simply ignore the results.

Comment: Agree with @Patrick. Simpler and easier to keep track of, and have your controllers handle when to reset the unique identifier, then the controller can ignore the response if it doesn't match the id.